# Binding Size of Canvas Background

Tags: wpf, image, canvas, background, size

I have a canvas that needs a graphical background using custom images of various sizes, but I want to bind the height and width of the background image to some properties somewhere. right now I have an image displaying as background but its size is fixed. It turns out that the width and height property of the image and of the imagebrush is readonly. Is there anyway to bind the width and height?

p.s I have tried viewport, but it uses a rect object and its width and height are not dependency properties. Then I tried to use one tile of the viewport and put it in a rectangle then I can resize the rectangle to achieve what I want but I cannot figure out how to put a rectangle as the canvas's background. Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way is to use a `VisualBrush` as the Background for the `Canvas`. Set Stretch to None and then bind the Width and Height of the `Image` in the `Visual`

```
<Canvas ...>
    <Canvas.Background>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Image Source="SomeSource"
                       Stretch="Fill"
                       Width="{Binding ...}"
                       Height="{Binding ...}"/>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Canvas.Background>
    <!--...-->
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't believe it was this simple.. I had Visual Brush, viewport, imagebrush and tons of stuff, got it to work but not nice and simple like this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say that i managed to follow what you're trying to do exactly, but you can use VisualBrush to put the Rectangle as the background of the canvas.

I'm somewhat sure that what you're doing can be solved easily - but I couldn't really understand what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry I don't really know how to explain this more clearly. I guess simply put it, i'm trying to resize the canvas background image dynamically during runtime using binding